# Authenticity of Hadith # 4424 Musnad Ahmad

Tags: hadith, hadith-interpretation, authenticity, uloom-al-hadith

Assalamu Alaikum Brothers in Islam,

Can you please provide me details regarding its authenticity from Silsilah Al Hadeeth Ad Daeefah from Al- Albani (ra) or from the commentary of other scholars?

The Hadith :

> ʻAbdullaah ibn Masʻood  may  Allaah  be  pleased  with  him said, “A
>   Jewish man passed by the Messenger of Allaah, sallallaahu ʻalayhi wa
>   sallam, while he was talking to some of his Companions. Some people
>   from Quraysh said to the Jewish man: “O Jew! This man claims that he
>   is a Prophet.” Thereupon, the Jewish man said: “I shall ask him about
>   something that only a Prophet would know.” He, then, came towards the
>   Prophet, sallallaahu ʻalayhi wa sallam, sat down and said: "O
>   Muhammad! From what is Man created?” The Messenger of Allaah,
>   sallallaahu ʻalayhi wa sallam, answered: “O Jew! Man is created from
>   the union of both the sperm-drop of the man and the sperm-drop of the
>   woman. As for the sperm-drop of man, it is thick and from it bones and
>   nerves are created, and the woman's sperm-drop, it is thin and from it
>   flesh and blood are created.” The Jewish man then stood up and said:
>   ‘This is what those before you (i.e. the Prophets) used to say.’”

Answer (score 2):

If you are asking with reference to the [islamweb](http://www.islamweb.net/en/fatwa/300712/index.php) answer.

- Al-Albani's Silsilat Al-Ahaadeeth Adh-Dhaʻeefah under number 5457 (٥٤٥٧): [scan](https://archive.org/stream/WAQdaifaa/daifaa11#page/n804/mode/2up) & [text](https://al-maktaba.org/book/12762/9855)
- Ahmad Shaakir's gradation and comments under number 4438 (٤٤٣٨): [scan](https://archive.org/stream/WAQmusndaWAQ/musnda04#page/n256/mode/2up) & [text](https://al-maktaba.org/book/33037/1935#p1)
- Al-Arnaa’oot and the co-authors's gradation and comments under number 4438 (٤٤٣٨):  [scan](https://archive.org/stream/waqmsnda/msnda07#page/n436/mode/2up) & [text](https://al-maktaba.org/book/25794/3354#p1)